# Invert cases within defined region

Tags: scala, case

I need to write a function which would invert cases in defined string region. 
"This operation does not change any other state variables"

Comment: have you try it on you own?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I need to write a function which would invert cases in defined string region." – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 0):

Scala is a functional language. It is not pure functional, that means that is not strict functional, but tends to go that way.

In pure functional programming variables are inmutable. That means that you cannot change (mutate) a variable value.

The type String in particular is inmutable for both Java and Scala.

When you do an operation on String, the JVM is creating a new one without modifying the original.

Note that the String is a new object created by the function

```
val strOriginal = "abc123"

def invertCase(str: String): String = {
  str.map(c => if (c.isUpper) c.toLower else c.toUpper)
}

val strNew = invertCase(strOriginal)

println(s"strOriginal ${strOriginal}")
println(s"newStr ${strNew}")
```

However if you use var, it works the same way, but it changes where `str` is referring

```
  var str = "abc123"

  println(s"str ${str}")

  def invertCase(str: String): String = {
    str.map(c => if (c.isUpper) c.toLower else c.toUpper)
  }

  str = invertCase(str)

  println(s"str ${str}")
```